# ReactJS comapre two objects inside componentdidupdate

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to add class based on previous props and currentprops in componentdid update.But its not giving an exact result as expected.Also showing syntax error.

Below is my code

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        const prev = prevProps.marketcap.map( (coin, i) => (
            {
                coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE < this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE ? 'ups' : 'down'
            }
        ));
        console.log(prev); //it will return an object containing ups or down..
    }
```

above `marketcap` is a props

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code, the curly braces around your ternary condition. This should work:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    const prev = prevProps.marketcap.map((coin, i) => (
       coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE < this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE ? 'ups' : 'down'
    ));
    console.log(prev); //it will return an object containing ups or down..
}
```